# Why does the interval where the differential equation makes sense not include $x = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the ODE equation $xy' = 2y$. A book states that the interval where it makes sense doesn't include $0$. Can you explain why? As to me, I think it is defined everywhere.

This problem is from the book "Ordinary Differential Equations - Harry Pollard, Morris Tenenbaum". The exact problem states: "Prove that the functions in the right-hand column below are solutions of the differential equations in the left-hand columns. (Be sure to state the common interval for which solution and differential equation make sense.)"

$xy' = 2y$ and $y = x^2$ with the answer $x \neq 0$

Comment: $y'$ might have a discontinuity at $x=0.$  But otherwise you can define a $y$ that fits the diff eq.

Comment: @DougM, how it might have a discontinuity?

Comment: The equation makes sense for $x=0$. It says that $y(x)=0$. If your interpretation of what the book is saying is accurate, then the book is wrong. A function that satisfies that equation for every $x$, must be of the form $y=Cx^2$ for $x\neq0$ and by continuity $y(0)=0$.

Comment: But check whether what they are saying is that or just excluding $x=0$ to then apply a method (say separation of variables, or integrating factor) to find the solution on $x\neq0$. Being the method, not the equation, the one that doesn't make sense for $x=0$.

Comment: I suspect your book intends to manipulate the equation into $\frac{y^\prime}{y} = \frac{2}{x}$ before solving, which is why they are (artificially) restricting $x$ to be nonzero.

Comment: @LB_O, I updated the question please check if I interpreted it right or not

Comment: Saw the book. Yes, the book is wrong even by their own definition of being a solution of a differential equation (Definition 3.4). If $y=x^2$, then for every $x$, we have that $y'=2x$ and therefore $xy'=2x^2=2y$. The point $x=0$ gives no problem.

Comment: @LB_O, what about the answer of LutzL? I find it pretty reasonable that if $x = 0$ then the differential equation disappears and there is no longer a differential equation to solve. Also, can you explain what is wrong with the definition?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov There is no contradiction. What he claimed in that sentence is a vague intuition of why $x=0$ is special. The equation $xy'-2y=0$ is a differential equation even at $x=0$, by your book's definition and pretty much everyone's definition. Bruce's answer, even though extremely short, is more precise on the role of the point $x=0$ in this differential equation.

Comment: @LB_O, although I didn't understand why you claimed the book is wrong by their own definition, I would like to know what can I do as the next step to understand Bruce's answer? I feel that there is a some huge concept behind the words "the solution may be analytic" but don't know what precisely it is.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov In my comment I checked that by the book's definition (which is almost everyone's definition) that $y=x^2$ is a solution of $xy'-2y=0$ for all $x$. The definition is just that the derivatives exist and that when you plug them in the equation the resulting equation in $x$ becomes an identity for all the $x$ in the domain claimed.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov If you haven't studied complex analysis then leave Bruce's answer for later. You can survive without it. Or dig a little in [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point). But the motivation I guess makes more sense when you have studied Chapter 11 (Existence and uniqueness theorems).

Answer (score 1):

As equation, as LB_O commented, the formula makes sense. However, the equation does not allow to determine a slope for $x=0$ for $y\ne 0$, and for $y=0$ the slope is arbitrary. In that view the equation is not a differential equation at $x=0$.

---

In general the domain of an ODE $y'=f(x,y)$ is an open set where $f$ is continuous. For an implicit ODE $0=F(x,y,y')$ one demands that $0=F(x,y,v)$ has at least one solution $v$ for any $(x,y)$ in the domain and that $\partial_vF(x,y,v)$ is invertible there, or that at least a unique continuous solution $v=f(x,y)$ exists locally around that point.

If the determination of the domain of the ODE is focused on the $x$-axis as in the given task, then the domain in question has the form $I\times \Bbb R^n$ where $I$ is an open interval. Thus if one point $(x,y)$ is not in the domain, then the whole line $\{x\}\times\Bbb R^n$ is not in the domain.

---

Note that if you look at continuous continuations of solutions of the given ODE in $x=0$, then the general solution is
$$
y(x)=\begin{cases}C_1x^2&\text{ for }x\ge 0,\\C_2x^2&\text{ for }x<0,\end{cases}
$$
with independent constants $C_1,C_2$.